# feathers-chat remote access fails to connect using VMware Fusion

Tags: socket.io, feathersjs

I built the feathers-chat demo with the feathers-chat-vuex client attached via socketio, but I am having trouble with remote access via socketio. The demo works fine as long as I access the client from a browser on the same system, which happens to be an Ubuntu VM running under VMware Fusion on a Macbook Pro. But if I try to connect to the client from a browser in the host MacOS, it brings up the login page but it fails to log in. In the devtools console, it says "WebSocket connection to ...localhost:3030 failed," which of course it did, because the feathers-chat server is not running on this localhost, it is running in the VM. The socketio is set up in feathers-client.js like this: "const socket = io('http://localhost:3030', {transports: ['websocket']})". If I hard-code the VM IP address in it like this: "const socket = io('http://172.16.184.194:3030', {transports: ['websocket']})" then the remote access works fine. But of course I cannot do that because in general I don't know the IP address of the server at run time. So can someone tell me the right way to set this up? Thanks!

Comment: Use some markdown to make this question readable. Split it in two or three paragraphs. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for further help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with the socketio on feathers but I've dealt with this on a rest feathers app (so hopefully this applies!).

Put the IP address into your config file. When you eventually deploy the app you will be pointing it at the IP address of the production server anyway so it makes sense to have it configurable.

Then for you local dev it can be the IP of the VM, and when you deploy your `config/production.json` can have the live IP.

Here's the docs about using config variables:
https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/configuration.html#example

**Update**
If you are using Docker instead of VMWare for your local development, then you can use docker-compose and use the built in networking functionality. Here is an example of a docker-compose file for feathers app that I'm working on. It's just an API so I'm not dealing with the client but I think it should be a good starting point for you.

With docker installed, put these two files in your project root and then run `docker-compose up -d`. It exposes the port 3030 on the feathers server and you should be able to connect with `http://localhost:3030` again from your host machine. If you want to add another docker container to docker-compose you can and then from that container you can access the server at `http://server:3030` because it will use the internal docker networking.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  server:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./protected_db/howlround-mongodb:/data/db
    command:
      - --storageEngine=mmapv1
```

And my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Dockerfile based on https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/6.4/slim/Dockerfile

# gpg keys listed at https://github.com/nodejs/node
RUN set -ex \
  && for key in \
    9554F04D7259F04124DE6B476D5A82AC7E37093B \
    94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 \
    0034A06D9D9B0064CE8ADF6BF1747F4AD2306D93 \
    FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E \
    71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 \
    DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D \
    B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9 \
    C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8 \
  ; do \
    gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key"; \
  done

ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL info
ENV NODE_VERSION 8.11.1
ENV NODE_ENV dev

RUN buildDeps='xz-utils curl ca-certificates' \
    && set -x \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y $buildDeps --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" \
    && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
    && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
    && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - \
    && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 \
    && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove $buildDeps

# Install yarn and feathers-cli
RUN npm install -g yarn @feathersjs/cli pm2@latest

# Install Git
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:git-core/ppa;\
  apt-get update;\
  apt-get -y install git

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN cd /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
RUN yarn install

EXPOSE 3030
CMD [ "node" ]
```

Comment: The problem is, I am working on an embedded app that will deploy on many boxes, perhaps in a docker. It is not clear to me how I can get the ip address of that particular box into the feather config.

Comment: If you are going to use docker then that is even better. I recommend switching to docker for you local development as well, it has networking features between containers that could be useful for you. My feathers development setup uses `docker-compose`. Then you can access one container from another on the same docker network using the container name. So if your server contain is called `server` then you can connect to `http://server:3030`.

Comment: I updated my answer with my feathers + docker local development setup in case that's helpful for your situation. I think that Docker is better than VMWare for local development, especially because you are considering deploying using docker in the end.

Comment: Any progress @Lannie?